# Sanity.io Fetching Through References

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I'm trying to figure out how to access a full object reference through Sanity.io. Example code:

```
const fetchExperience = async () => {
  const data = await sanityClient.fetch(`*[_type == 'experience'] {
    company,
    title,
    'techStack': stack[]->technology,
    'imageUrl': image.asset->url,
  }`);

  return data;
};
```

I have another schema declared called `Skill` that contains two fields: technology, and icon. This `Experience` schema that I am working with above and references the `Skill` schema. Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428988/how-to-retrieve-a-referenced-field-data-inside-inputcomponent-in-sanity-io?rq=1#), I was able to figure out how to grab a singular field through the reference and populate a field called `techStack`. However, I want to take this one step further: how can I write a GROQ that returns me an array of objects that might look like this?:

```
[
  { technology: 'React.js', icon: 'pretend-this-is-a-link-to-an-asset' },
  ...
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Are you trying to extend the `fetchExperience()` query, or write a new one? And how do experiences reference skills? You can do `'techStack': stack[]-> { technology, icon }` to get the specific fields, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: @AlexanderStaubo that was exactly what I was looking for, lol. If you want to answer the question, I'll mark your answer as the accepted solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get the specific fields:

```
"techStack": stack[]-> { technology, icon }
```

Comment: Not with GraphQL though.

Comment: also thinking about a clean way to fetch reference fields via GraphQL